# Laravel - is there some kind of `fill()` method but when working with pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel you can call a `fill()` method on a model that would update model attributes but won't persist it to the database.

Is there a similar functionality when working with pivot tables and Many to Many relationship?

```
$order->items()
        ->newPivotStatement()
        ->where('item_id', $item_id)
        ->where('order_id', $order->id)
        ->update([
            'qty' => $quantity,
            'containers' => $containers,
        ]);
```

so the `update` section is where I'm interested - can I `Fill` the pivot table attributes, but don't persist it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that you can probably try and do it with [Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), just scroll a bit down until you reach a header where it says `Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a new **model** for your *pivot* table which extends from

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;`